# how to show dialog box before downloading the dynamically generated pdf?

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET, C# and iTextSharp for creating a PDF. 
Then I am using this code for transmitting the file.

```
Response.TransmitFile(filename);
```

So I want to display a dialog box which will request the user whether to open/save/cancel when they click on the generate button.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?.... dot com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Responce.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachement;filename=name.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(filename);
```

Here content-disposition is the one which is used for displaying the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it to the response directly. Browser will show the save as/open depending on the type sent.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Downloads\Test.pdf");
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Thanks..but what if he don't have that download folder or don't have access to C:\..

Comment: That was just a sample path. Give it the path to where ever you generated the file. If you are generating the file in memory, you can write the bytes directly to the `Response.OutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, is the navigator who decides make the download for load it inside navigator.

Normally the unique way to download it is offer a link and guide the user to right click and to choose Save As